# Android post method in one class

Tags: android

Hi I have this post method in every activity. How can I put this post into one class such that if error I will know? Otherwise, I will be parsing the error message as json.

```
private boolean login(String username, String password) {
    TextView err = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.err);
    boolean status = false;
    String postData = "{\"Password\":\"" + password + "\",\"UserName\":\"" + username + "\"}";
    try {
        String domain = getString(R.string.domain);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(domain + "login");
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(postData.toString(), "utf-8");
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        httppost.setEntity(se);
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        if (response != null) {
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
            String json = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(json);
            status = jsonobj.getBoolean("result"); 
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        err.setText(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--either put it in a super class, or create a utility class that has the method?

Answer (score 0):

Make a util class. and make this method static

```
public static boolean login(String username, String password,TextView err){}
```

you can also pass it context if you need. then call this method as where you need

```
util.login( username,  password,errorTextView);
```

Comment: So if I pass in my textview the error message will be shown on my activity? Will it return false?

Comment: if you are using this method in background thread then you cannot use textview.you only update textview on uithread. use AsyncTask and on post execute return a string and update your textview .

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it synchronously and return status. However, it seems your question is how to get a status asynchronously. In such a case, you might:

1. create an Interface (or base class) which has a method like receivedPostStatus(boolean)
2. pass something that implements the Interface (or is subclassed from the base class) into an AsyncTask subclass which does the HTTP POST in its doInBackground()
3. then in AsyncTask.onPostExecute, call myImplementer.receivedPostStatus(status)